# Access - Is it possible to execute a saved INSERT query from within a CREATE TABLE query?

Tags: ms-access

I was wondering if it is possible to execute a saved INSERT query from within a CREATE TABLE query?
The Idea being, once table X is created, an insert query will immediately fire off and populate the new table with data from table Y.
I was hoping it was something similar to sql where you can execute stored procedure y from strored procedure x. 
Here is what i've got so far:
**CREATE TABLE MatureStudents(StudentNumber NUMBER) EXECUTE InsertInToMatureStudentsQuery();**

Comment: @SQLis already mentioned make query. It creates table based on query. I believe this should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

> ... possible to execute a saved INSERT query from within a CREATE
>   TABLE query?

No.  The Access database engine will not execute batches of SQL statements under any circumstances.

You must execute the `CREATE TABLE` as one query and then execute the `INSERT` as a separate query --- not both in one.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you put this all in the same query (Access Make Table query)?
Or you can use a macro that will first create your table and then run your saved Insert query.

Comment: A macro will suffice, however it would be preferable to do this from within the CREATE TABLE query, if possible.

Comment: If a macro will suffice, consider doing this in VBA instead.  Better control, more flexibility.  You can put it all inside the same Sub or Function, and just call that Sub or Function from wherever you are (I assume you're doing this in the OnClick event of a button?).